# Change 'checked' property of checkbox using jQuery and bootstrap (AdminLTE theme)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [AdminLTE](http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/index.html) theme (which implements bootstrap) and I have a checkbox on my page. It gets rendered as follows -

```
<div class="icheckbox_minimal" style="position: relative;" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false">
<input id="subscribeAddress" type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
</div>
```

[image]

(note how a sprite is used to display the checkbox, while the actual input element is given an opacity of 0)

I now wish to change the checked property of the checkbox with jQuery. How would I go about doing this? I have tried the following without any luck -

```
$("#subscribeAddress").prop("checked", true);

$(".icheckbox_minimal").prop("aria-checked", true);
```

**Update:** I have found a solution to my question and posted an answer below, but am still open to suggestions on better approaches.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that adding the "checked" class to div of class "icheckbox_minimal" is what I was looking for.

Is directly modifying this div considered to be the correct way to do this? Or should I be another way?

I'll leave my question unanswered for a little while, to give someone a chance to supply a better answer (if one exists). I feel like marking my own answer is cheating :p

Comment: This is web-application specific and does not answer the general question asked.

Answer (score 4):

try below code

```
$("#subscribeAddress").iCheck('uncheck');
```

Answer (score 0):

how about plain old-fashioned javascript?

```
document.getElementById("subscribeAddress").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#subscribeAddress").prop("checked", true);` works fine.

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwxa96wa/) for it.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question to make things clearer. When using the AdminLTE theme, it seems that a sprite is used to display the checkbox while the actual input element is given an opacity of 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('#checkAll').on('ifChanged', function(event){
    if(this.checked){
        $('input').iCheck('check')
    }
    else{
        $('input').iCheck('uncheck')
    }
})
```

**I hope this will help you.**